# Matching multiple attribs with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

So i have a bunch of records like `{A: x, B: y}`.

I would like to construct a search query that match both `A` and `B` attrib.

However, adding 1 more criteria into `match`, the query would fail to parse.

This works.

```
{
   "query" : {
       "match": {
           "A": "x"
       }
   }
}
```

This doesn't.

```
{
   "query" : {
       "match": {
           "A": "x",
           "B": "y"
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
      "must": [
          {
             "match": {"A": "x"}
          },
          {
             "match": {"B": "y"}
          }
       ]
    }
   }
 }
```

Use `must` to `AND` all your match clauses, use `should` to `OR` all match clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Using term query, try this:

```
{
   "query": {
       "bool": {
          "should": [
              {
                "term": {"A": "x"}
              },
              {
                "term": {"B": "y"}
              }
          ]
       }
   }
}
```

or match query can do this:

```
{
   "query": {
       "bool": {
          "should": [
              {
                 "match": {"A": "x"}
              },
              {
                 "match": {"B": "y"}
              }
           ]
        }
     }
 }
```